# Jersey 1.19 Test configuration - mock classes

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mockito, jersey-test-framework

I want to test my REST service with:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have configuration class:

```
public class MyServiceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected int getPort(int defaultPort) {
        return 8080;
    }

    public static class AppConfig extends DefaultResourceConfig {
        public AppConfig() {
            super(MyService.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WebAppDescriptor configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder()
        .initParam(WebComponent.RESOURCE_CONFIG_CLASS, 
                AppConfig.class.getName())
                .build();
    }

    public MyServiceTest(){

    }
}
```

MyService.java is REST endpoint which has injected DAO and other services. There are setters for them in MyService.java for mocking purposes. How to provide MyService instance with set/mocked related classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked with

```
public static class AppConfig extends DefaultResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {

        MyService myService = new MyService();
        MyDAO myDAO = mock(MyDAO.class);
        myService.setMyDAO(myDAO);

        getSingletons().add(new ExceptionMapperProvider()); 
        getSingletons().add(myService);
    }
}
```